# i am unable to figure out how the below code produce output as ffffffaa please help me understand?

Tags: c, pointers

Hello  i am unable to figure out how the below code produce
output as ffffffaa
  please help me understand

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
  int a=0xaaaaaaaa;
  char *p=(char*)&a;
  printf("%x\n",*p);
}
```

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdio.h>`? `int a = 0xaaaaaaaa;` will assign an implementation-defined value to `a` (unless `int` is wider than 32 bits on your system); using `unsigned int` would be clearer. The code in your question cannot produce the output you describe (`%d` prints decimal, not hexadecimal); please update your question to show the actual code you're running.

Answer (score 5):

Variadic functions like `printf` perform the *default argument promotion* on its trailing arguments.  A `char` is promoted to an `int` and when `char` is signed on the platform a sign extension is performed.

To avoid the sign extension use `unsigned char` types or cast `*p` to `unsigned char` in the `printf` call of your program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to figure out how the code above can produce `ffffffaa` because it cannot do that with a `"%d"` specifier ;-).

You probably mistyped you code sample and it should read:

```
int main() {
    int a=0xaaaaaaaa;
    char *p=(char*)&a;
    printf("%x\n",*p);
}
```

For this code to produce `ffffffaa`, char must be 8 bit signed, and int must be stored in little endian order or have a size of at most 32 bits.

`&a` is the address of the first byte of `a` in memory.  Dereferencing this address as a `char *` loads one byte and sign extends it as an `int` before passing it to `printf` as this function is variadic. Extra arguments to variatic functions with types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` and passed as such, and floating point types smaller than `double` are promoted to `double` and passed as such.  `printf` receives an `int` but prints the hexadecimal representation of an `unsigned int` for the format specifier `%x`.  It's a good thing `int` and `unsigned int` are passed the same way ;-)

Since the value `0xaaaaaaaa` has the same representation in little endian and big endian order, your code will not depend on endianness as long as `int` is 32 bits or less.  But on a machine with 64 bit `int` in big endian order (such as some late PowerPCs), the actual memory layout of `a` would be `00 00 00 00 aa aa aa aa`.  Your code would then produce `0` output.

You can learn about endianness with this code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(void) {
    int i, a = 0x12345678;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&a;
    printf("Memory layout for %x is:", a);
    for (i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(a); i++)
        printf(" %02x", p[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Different compilers may produce different output on the same machine if they target a different architecture (32 vs 64 bits).